# Compute upper limit of $(c_n)^{1/n}$ if $c_{2n}=0$ and $c_{2n+1}=1/(2n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find the upper limit of $\left((c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $c_n=0$ for $n\in 2\mathbb{N}$ and $c_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in 2\mathbb{N}+1$. I know that the upper limit is 1, but how can i prove it?
My idea was to establish $\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $\phi(n)=2n+1$ and then I have all my nonzero elements, so that $c_{\phi(n)}$=$\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your notations are off. You are asking for the "upper limit" (that is, the limsup) of $(c_n)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$(c_n)^\frac1n \le \frac1{\sqrt[n]n}\le 1$$

is strictly increasing for $n\ge 2$ and for $n=2k+1$

$$(c_n)^\frac1n=\frac1{\sqrt[2k+1]{2k+1}}\to 1$$